# Difference b/w Chrome Color, Content Backgrond Color & Background color in flex 4

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

Could anyone please explain the difference between the Chrome Color, Content Background Color and the Background color in flex 4.

Answer (score 3):

in a nutshell:

- chromeColor:
  The main color of the component.
   The default skins are all based on various shades of gray. The chromeColor is applied as a color transformation (tinting), which preserves all of the visual fidelity of the default appearance. Items colorized by other color style values are not affected by chromeColor
- contentBackgroundColor: The color of the content area of components that contain content.
- backgroundColor: Was used in earlier versions of Flex, only available on some `mx:` components

Cheers